# Pandas: Keep only first occurance of value in group of consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following (actually, this is the abstracted result of a calculation):

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"A":[i for i in range(10)]}
index = [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 20]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data)
print(df)
```

yields:

```
A
1   0
3   1
4   2
5   3
9   4
10  5
12  6
13  7
15  8
20  9
```

Now I want to filter the index values to only show the first value in a group of consecutive values e. g. the following result:

```
A
1   0
3   1
9   4
12  6
15  8
20  9
```

Any hints on how to achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) which is not implemented for `Index`, so convert to `Series` and compre for not equal `1`:

```
df = df[df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1)]
print (df)
    A
1   0
3   1
9   4
12  6
15  8
20  9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like this solution because it only needs a pandas import.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
import numpy as np

df.iloc[np.unique(np.array(index)-np.arange(len(index)), return_index=True)[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have accepted the other answer as it seems to be a bit simper :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
`df.groupby('A').index.first().reset_index()`

Comment: this doesnt work by the way

Comment: Thank you Vladislava for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: @mozway: There's no indication that athing downvoted this—but, if it doesn't work, that's a perfectly valid reason to downvote an answer. And, if they did, following that up with a comment explaining why is far more of a courtesy than most downvoters provide. Still, I'd like to understand _why_ athing believes it doesn't work; to your point, that would be far more constructive.